# Composer create-project yiisoft/yii2-app-basic basic to specific yii2 release?

Tags: php, performance, yii2, composer-php

I am trying to create yii2 demo application using https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/start-installation and I would like to have application with high performance. I failed to do this with the latest Yii2 version i.e. [Impossible to get PHP Yii waiting TTFB time under 2s (with profiling results)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51156256/impossible-to-get-php-yii-waiting-ttfb-time-under-2s-with-profiling-results) and that is why I would like to create Yii2 basic application using older Yii2 version. Does `composer create-project` command have some options that allow to specify previous release of Yii2.

Comment: does editing `composer.json` putting your Yii version and run `composer update` help? I would delete the `.lock` file first. That is after normal installation is done as per Yii2 guide

Comment: yes, there is a way, just add at the end of your command the version that you want, the list of all version can be found here: [YII2 Releases](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-basic/releases)

example: `composer create-project yiisoft/yii2-app-basic basic 2.0.4`